# How would I convert these four lines of code from AVAudioPlayer to AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, avplayer

I need to change my code from `AVAudioPlayer` to `AVPlayer` because it supports rewind and `AVAudioPlayer` doesn't. Im having trouble with these four lines of code that seeks the audio thats playing using a slider. Here is the code I have:

```
func changeAudioTime() {

    //musicPlayer is declared as AVAudioPlayer and I want to change it to  AVPlayer and I named the variable player

    musicPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    musicPlayer.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(slider.value)
    musicPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1
    slider.value = Float(musicPlayer.currentTime)

}
```

Comment: Just refer this link may be it's help it out https://github.com/davestitz/iOS-AvPlayer-Demo   and https://github.com/mikeMTOL/KSVideoPlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting the time in both the case you can use this:

```
self.player.seekToTime(CMTimeMake(Int64(slider.value),1))
slider.value = Float(CMTimeGetSeconds(self.player.currentTime()))
```

For looping you may try like this, as there is no direct method of loop, till you want to repeat you may set flag/observer and repeat the song if repeat is off you can don't execute observer/seek

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:",name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
object: self.player.currentItem)

func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    self.player.play()
}
```